# Get result of Google Search API with PHP

Tags: php, google-search-api

I want to get result from Google as the guide on https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/#php-access for PHP language. I don't understand why it not working.

This is my code:

```
$url =  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"
. "q=Paris%20Hilton";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com');
    $body = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json = json_decode($body,true);
```

I debug it then see $body is false & $json is null. I hope to get your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to access directly in your browser the URL: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Paris%20Hilton. It's invalid! That's why it's not working...

Comment: i don't know what it is missing

Comment: What your code does is to query the URL you assigned to the variable `$url` (which is the one I suggested you to check in my answer)... The reason you're getting `false` and `null` for `$body` and `$json` is that the URL you're trying to access is no longer available, as you can see when you type it in your browser's address bar and hit "Enter"... Try it yourself...

Answer (score 1):

In the [Web Search API docs](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/), Google says:

> The Google Web Search API is [officially deprecated](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/11/introducing-google-apis-console-and-our.html) as of November 1, 2010. Per our [deprecation policy](https://developers.google.com/web-search/terms) it operated for more than three years past its deprecation date. Its last day of operation was September 29, 2014. We encourage you to investigate the [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/), which may provide an alternative solution.